# Why is setuptools not available in environment Ubuntu docker image with Python & dev tools installed?

Tags: python, docker, setuptools, requirements.txt

I'm trying to build a Ubuntu 18.04 Docker image running Python 3.7 for a machine learning project. When installing specific Python packages with `pip` from `requirements.txt`, I get the following error:

```
Collecting sklearn==0.0
  Downloading sklearn-0.0.tar.gz (1.1 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [1 lines of output]
      ERROR: Can not execute `setup.py` since setuptools is not available in the build environment.
      [end of output]
```

Although here the error arises in the context of `sklearn`, the issue is not specific to one library; when I remove that libraries and try to rebuild the image, the error arises with other libraries.

Here is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

# install python
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y \
    python3.7 python3-pip python3.7-dev

# copy requirements
WORKDIR /opt/program
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt

# install requirements
RUN python3.7 -m pip install --upgrade pip && \
    python3.7 -m pip install -r requirements.txt

# set up program in image
COPY . /opt/program
```

What I've tried:

- installing `python-devtools`, both instead of and alongside, `python3.7-dev` before installing requirements with `pip`;
- installing `setuptools` in `requirements.txt` before affected libraries are installed.

In both cases the same error arose.

Do you know how I can ensure `setuptools` is available in my environment when installing libraries like `sklearn`?

Comment: Does installing `setuptools` with `pip` before running `pip install -r requirements.txt` solves your issue? It is different than putting `setuptools` higher in the requirements.txt because it forces the order while the requirements file collect all the packages and installs them after so you don't control the order.

Comment: Yes, that solved my issue! Please feel free to post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As mentioned in comment, install `setuptools` with `pip` before running `pip install -r requirements.txt`.

It is different than putting `setuptools` higher in the `requirements.txt` because it forces the order while the requirements file collect all the packages and installs them after so you don't control the order.

Comment: If I do that, I still get this and the same issue: # pip3.10 install setuptools
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /root/.pyenv/versions/3.10.4/envs/ansible/lib/python3.10/site-packages (58.1.0)

Comment: pip uninstall setuptools && pip install setuptols did the job for me.

Comment: pip install -U setuptools worked for me